# Table access permission restriction in MS Access

Tags: sql, delphi, ms-access, permissions, dbtable

How can I restrict the access of a table just for one specific db user in MS Access by SQL DDL statemets?

Comment: See GRANT and REVOKE here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177904(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: If your database format is 2007+ (accdb) you can't.

Comment: I think you should remove a delphi tag in this regard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Grant and Revoke statements

```
REVOKE {privilege[, privilege, …]} ON {TABLE table | OBJECT object|

CONTAINTER container} FROM {authorizationname[, authorizationname, …]}
```

Syntax

```
GRANT {privilege[, privilege, …]} ON {TABLE table | OBJECT object|

CONTAINER container } TO {authorizationname[, authorizationname, …]}
```

see more: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177904%28v=office.12%29.aspx